# Tabulator duplicated record when using grouping column header

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I use the example from the website to test the column group but it will duplicate the row record
is tabulator does not support col group with HTML element ?
Once I remove the col group , it will become normal
thank you
[The test result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EegR.jpg)

My code:

```
   <table id="example-table">
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >Name</th>
            <th >Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Driver</th>
            <th>favouritecolor</th>
            <th>dob</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Billy Bob</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>yesdrive</td>
            <td>red</td>
            <td>22/04/1994</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary May</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>yesdrive</td>
            <td>blue</td>
            <td>14/05/1982</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columnHeaderVertAlign:"bottom", //align header contents to bottom of cell

    columns:[
    {title:"Name", field:"name", width:160},
    {//create column group
        title:"Work Info",
        columns:[
        {title:"Age", field:"age"},
        {title:"Height", field:"height"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"driver"},
        ],
    },
    {//create column group
        title:"Personal Info",
        columns:[
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
        {title:"favouritecolor", field:"favouritecolor"},
        {title:"dob", field:"dob"},
        ],
    },
    ],
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator can only support importing simple HTML Tables, as the documentation states:

> Note: Tabulator can only parse simple tables. Tables using multiple
> header rows, colspan or rowspan attributes will cause the import to
> fail.

That being said you can easily add column groups to a Tabulator, you just need to define your table setup using a column definition object array instead.

Full details of how to setup a tables column definition can b found in the [Columns Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/columns)

An example of column groups in action can be found in the [Column Groups Example](http://tabulator.info/examples/5.1#column-groups)